# Функция преобразования списка в словарь

Tags: python, функции, list, словари

В этом новичок. Читаю книгу Эл Свейгарта. Помогите с решением данной задачи.

```
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v) + ' ' + k)
        item_total += v
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    # здесь должен быть код..

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rupy': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby'] 
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragoonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

Должно вывести:

```
Inventory:
45 gold coin
1 rope
1 ruby
1 dagger
Total number of items: 48
```

Ну, то есть, нужно обновить словарь `inv` новыми данными из списка `dragonLoot`

Comment: а почему получилось 45 ?

Comment: потому что 'gold coin' в списке dragonLoot[] встречается 3 раза. Это и остальные значения должны как бы добавится / обновиться в словаре inv{}

Answer (score 1):

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):       
    for x in addedItems:
        # если нет такого,установим в 0
        inventory.setdefault(x, 0)
        inventory[x] += 1
    return inventory
```

Comment: Оказывается так просто. Спасибо!

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]